# Cual es la diferencia entre la division / de numero flotante y la division // de numero entero?

Tags: python

```html
#Get a number of seconds from the user
total_seconds = float(input('Enter a number of seconds: '))

#Get the number of hours
hours = total_seconds // 3600

#Get the number of remaining minutes
minutes = (total_seconds // 60) % 60

#Get the number of remaining seconds
seconds = total_seconds % 60

#Display the result
print('Here is the time in hours, minutes, and seconds:')
print('Hours:', hours)
print('Minutes:', minutes)
print('Seconds:', seconds)
```

Tengo una duda acerca de los operadores de division '/' y '//'.
realice este ejemplo sacado de un libro pero estoy confudido en la operation que sea realizo. cuando ingreso el numero en forma de entero para los segundos entiendo que se convierte en flotante pero en los operacion para obtener las horas, minutos y segundos entro mi confusion al utilizar la operacion de division para numeros enteros (total_seconds // 3600) el resultado deberia ser entero pero el resultado sale flotante. es hay donde que entro mi confusion. porque no se utilizo la division para flotantes. alguien me podria explicar porque pasa esto.

Comment: la primera `/` hara la division y regresara hasta los decimales y la `//` regresara un entero!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se trata de que un operando es para "flotantes" y otro para "enteros", la diferencia entre los dos operandos no radica en el tipo de los argumentos/operandos de entrada, la diferencia esta en la operación que hace cada uno de ellos.

Ambos operadores aceptan  cualquier tipo numérico como operandos (con la excepción de los complejos, que no definen la operación `//`). Puedes usar ambos operadores con `int`, `float`, `decimal.Decimal` y `fraction.Fraction`, incluso puedes usar distinto tipo para cada operando si la operación esta definida para esos tipos, por ejemplo, son validas las siguientes operaciones:

> ```
> int / int           -> float
> int / float         -> float
> int / Decimal       -> Decimal
> int / Fraction      -> Fraction
> int / complex       -> complex
>
> float / int         -> float
> float / float       -> float
> float / fraction    -> float
> float / complex     -> complex
>
> Fraction / int      -> Fraction
> Fraction / float    -> float
> Fraction / Fraction -> Fraction
> Fraction / complex  -> complex
>
> Decimal / int       -> Decimal
> Decimal / Decimnal  -> Decimal
>
> complex / int       -> complex
> complex / float     -> complex
> complex / Fraction  -> complex
> complex / complex   -> complex
> ```

> ```
> int // int           -> int
> int // float         -> float
> int // Decimal       -> Decimal
> int // Fraction      -> int
>
> float // int         -> float
> float // float       -> float
> float // fraction    -> float
>
> Fraction // int      -> int
> Fraction // float    -> float
> Fraction // Fraction -> int
>
> Decimal // int       -> Decimal
> Decimal // Decimnal  -> Decimal
> ```

La diferencia entre ambos operadores radica en la operación que cada uno hace:

- `a / b` realiza el cociente entre `a` y `b`, no hay mucho mas que decir... Si nos restringimos a operandos `int` y `float`, se realiza la división en coma flotante y el resultado sera un `float`. Obviamente si la división no es exacta el resultado tendrá decimales. Puedes hacer que cualquier clase soporte este operando implementando el método `__truediv__` en ella.
- `a // b` realiza la "división entera" entre `a` y `b`. Aunque la implementación difiere dependiendo de los operandos, lo que hace básicamente es **aplicar la función suelo (o piso) al cociente entre `a` y `b`**. En este caso su método de sobrecarga es `__floordiv__`.

  **El resultado es siempre por definición un numero entero, aunque el tipo de salida no siempre es `int`** como vemos en la tabla de arriba. Por ejemplo, `4 // 2` es 2 y el tipo de salida sera `int`, `4.0 // 2` también es 2 pero el tipo de salida es `float`. Esto pasa porque en el caso de que uno de los operandos sea `float`, se aplica un casting al otro operando para convertirlo en `float` también y se aplica el método `floordiv` de `float`, que da como resultado otro `float` (todo esto es algo mas complejo en realidad, ya que esta implementado en C, el casting es a double, ...).

  Es cierto que se podría haber decidido que el operador siempre retornara un objeto `int`, pero esto implica hacer un casting extra en muchos casos que en realidad no suele aportar nada pero si aumentaría el coste computacional de la operación. El tipo de salida depende de los tipos de los operandos de entrada y es el que es por diversas razones dependiendo del caso, desde eficiencia, detalles de la implementación en C de la operación, consistencia con otras operaciones definidas para esos tipos, etc. Si se necesita que sea un `int` siempre podemos aplicar nosotros el casting explícitamente: `int(7.3 // 2)`

El operador `/` no tiene mas misterio creo:

```
>>> 4 / 2
2.0

>>> -3 / 7
-0.42857142857142855

>>> 4.23 / 8.74
0.48398169336384445

>>> complex(4, 3) / 5
(0.8+0.6j)

>>> Fraction(4, 3) / Fraction(5, 16)
Fraction(64, 15)
```

Quizás si podemos profundizar algo mas en la división entera. Lo primero es aclarar que es la función suelo.

La función suelo o piso es una función de parte entera (función que a partir de un numero real retorna un entero) que dado un numero *n* devuelve el **máximo número entero no superior a *n***. Es decir:

> ```
> floor(4) = 4
> floor(4.3) = 4
> floor(4.9) = 4
> floor(-4) = -4
> floor(-4.3) = -5
> floor(-4.9) = -5
> ```

Es importante entender esto porque hay gente que cree que el operador `//` realiza un truncado del cociente, es decir, que se queda con la parte entera de la división despreciando la parte decimal, cuando en realidad aplica la función suelo. Hay que tener en cuenta que la función suelo equivale al truncado (o redondeo sobre cero) solo si el numero es positivo.

Por ejemplo, -13 entre 4:

```
>>> -13 / 4
-3.25
```

Si aplicáramos un truncado al cociente el resultado seria -3, pero:

```
>>> -13 // 4
-4
```

y esto se debe a a que si aplicamos la función suelo sobre -3.25, el entero máximo menor a -3.25 es -4 (porque -3 > -3.25).

En los casos en los que el resultado de la división es un numero positivo, el operador `//` simplemente retorna la parte entera del cociente descartando la parte decimal (dado que en este caso la función suelo no difiere del truncado):

```
>>> 13 / 4
3.25
>>> 13 // 4
3
```

en este caso es mas intuitivo aplicar eso de cuando aprendíamos a dividir de

> "Trece entre cuatro es tres y me sobra uno..."

y ese "uno" que me sobra, o resto, se calcula con otro operador (el operador modulo `%`), eso es para otro día, pero siempre se deberá cumplir que:

> (a // b) * b + a % b = a

```
>>> -13 // 4 * 4 + -13 % 4
-13
```

Aunque el resultado de los operadores `//` y `%` de Python desconcierte a mucha gente cuando están implicados números negativos por la decisión de hacer uso de la función suelo.